# :promt in Rails select() helper not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

I have next string in my form template(from book 'Agile web development with Rails'):

```
    <%= f.select :pay_type, Order::PAYMENTS_TYPES, promt: 'Select a payment method' %>
```

When form is being visited with browser, there is not default "promt" for select field indicated. What is the problem?

UPD I'm using Rails v4.0.2
UPD Html output(in the browser):

```
 <div class="field">
    <label for="order_pay_type">Pay type</label><br>
    <select id="order_pay_type" name="order[pay_type]"><option value="Check">Check</option>
<option value="Credit card">Credit card</option>
<option value="Purchase order">Purchase order</option></select>
  </div>
```

Comment: can you please post the error ?

Comment: @HaiderAli there is no error displayed, I can post a html output in the browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misspelled it. It should be the`prompt:` not `promt`

```
<%= f.select :pay_type, Order::PAYMENTS_TYPES, prompt: 'Select a payment method' %>
```

Comment: your welcome @Kavachaj, it happens too many times with me also.. :)